# Errors while deploying chaincode using IBM blockchain platform extension in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric

I tried using the sample chaincode of the go version, but failed many times.
The error information of VsCode is as followed

```
Failed to install on peer Org1 Peer with reason: Could not install smart contact received error: failed with status:500 ::failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: external builder failed: external builder failed to build: external builder 'golang' failed: exit status 1
```

But it works normally when using the javascript version.
I hope to use the golang to develop my project, what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/wiki/Errors-&-Fixes and follow the steps related to your setup/versions.